# Am I likely to get a UK visitor visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a university student currently in my second year, and I wish to visit my partner, a UK national living outside of the uk in a separate country from my own.

He's completely capable of sponsoring my trip however my financial situation is concerning me. My bank statements show deposits from my friend abroad every couple of months and some deposits from me, usually less than $200 as I am unemployed just a student. I'm not sure how to explain any of these deposits for my application however my statements have had a consistent amount of money for the past 6 months. Can I  explain these funds in my cover letter?

Comment: are you seeking a uk visa? Are you and your partner both going to visit the uk together?

Comment: Your friend abroad will need to provide you with their bank statements showing the source of the funds you receive, which you will submit along with evidence of the source of your own deposits. There are many questions on this topic on TSE